# Firefox IFrame Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, html-frames

I have a problem with firefox adding unnecessary scroll-bars (its working ok in chrome and ie).

See the following two files: page.html & iframe.html.

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myframe {
            height: 550px;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 665px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#dcdcdc;">
        <iframe id="myframe" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" src="iframe.html" style="display: inline;">
        </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html {
            direction: rtl;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 665px; height: 537px; background-color: blue;">
        x
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In firefox v30 i always get vertical and horizontal scroll-bars showing.
The size of the content in iframe.html is the same as the iframe tag size.

I narrowed the problem down to using direction:rtl tag in the iframe.html file.
When i add the direction:rtl i get the scrollbars and removing it fixes the problem.

Any idea why ?

How to fix this without using scrolling="no" on the iframe ?

**Edit:**
I dont think adding overflow:hidden is the solution, the content should not "overflow" - its smaller then the parent.
Also i'd like to have the option for content to overflow and show scrollbars in-case that the content is long.

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: try using overflow hidden in the contained html element that holds the text.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
<iframe id="myframe" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" src="iframe.html" style="display: inline;">
```

with this:

```
<iframe id="myframe" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  src="iframe.html" style="display: inline;">
```

Alternative add !important at the end of the css rule

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myframe {
        height: 550px;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        width: 665px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you think i need overflow: hidden if the content size in the iframe isn't too big ?

Comment: You asked how to remove the scrollbar from the iframe without removing the iframe attribute scrolling. So I replied to your question, the reasons why you want it like this, I have no idea. But a good practise would be, to remove all attributes from your iframe, define all them with css, put border: none; overflow: hidden, etc, and then inside the html document handle scrollbar etc. Also another "way" to fix your issue may be setting box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Just thinking, have you tried to press control+0 on your browser? maybe you are with a zoom different than 100% and this creates scrollbars :)

Comment: zoom on firefox is at 100%

Comment: That's really strange, I have tested it same code as you have on my firefox and I don't have any scrollbar.. can you check if when you inspect them, if is there any new css rule or something that you haven't post to us?

Comment: I've copy&paste from code i posted here and tested again , i still get scroll-bars on firefox v30. I also tried on another computer - same problem.  On which browser version did you test ?

Comment: Firefox 30.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: can you try #myframe { (..) overflow: auto !important; (..) }, the only explanation, could be the priority used at the time of rendering but is weird..

Answer (score 0):

Set the style of iframe to overflow:hidden...

```
<iframe id="myframe" style="display: inline; overflow: hidden; border: 0; margin: 0" scrolling="auto" src="iframe.html" >
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you think i need overflow: hidden if the content size in the iframe isn't too big ?